# How to copy value from a cell in MSExcel into a field in MSWord file with VB Code?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to have a vb code in ms word 2003 that copy a a specific cell in excel file and paste it in word (filed). Below is what I have done and it result in error.

```
Sub cmdGetNumber()
Dim XL As Object
Dim WBEx As Object
Dim ExelWS As Object
Dim appwd As Object
Dim wdApp As Word.Application

''''

'On Error GoTo OLE_ERROR
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Open Excel document
Set WBEx = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\121567\Desktop\tafket1.xls")
Set ExelWS = WBEx.Worksheets("Sheet1")
XL.Visible = True
'appwd.Visible = True

ExelWS.Range("c2").Select
'Selection.Copy

'wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
'wdApp.Documents.Save
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set ExelWS = Nothing
Set WBEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try wdPasteText or wdPasteRTF instead of wdPasteMetafilePicture?

Comment: Please paste the error text onto the end of you question.

Answer (score 2):

Since this macro is in Word, you don't need to explicitly open a word instance. You can just do `Documents.Add` to add a new document, or `Documents.Open` to open an existing one.

Try this:

```
Sub cmdGetNumber()
    Dim XL As Object
    Dim WBEx As Object
    Dim ExelWS As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    'On Error GoTo OLE_ERROR
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Open Excel document
    Set WBEx = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\121567\Desktop\tafket1.xls")
    Set ExelWS = WBEx.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'XL.Visible = True
    ExelWS.Range("C2").Copy

    Set wdDoc = Documents.Add
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdDoc.Select
    Selection.Paste

    WBEx.Close
    XL.Quit
    Set WBEx = Nothing
    Set ExelWS = Nothing
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code will open your excel file, copy the cell C2, then open a new word document, and paste it there.

I see you have mentioned a `(filed)` in your question. Did you mean a `Field` or a `File`? If it is a `Field` then you may want to replace `Selection.Paste` with the relevant field name